# Glass material is not showing certain objects

Tags: rendering, glass

As you can see I am trying to put my head in a jar
[image]

but the lid and base of my jar are not showing up
[image]

I am using Evee and both objects that dont appear just have a texture on them

Comment: is it the same from different camera angles? could it be just the refraction of the glass material? (Also why you're putting the glass in front of the 'jar'?)

Comment: Hey Luciano. It was having the same effect when inside. Also the head is at the same distance as the base but I can still see it